# Why does Visual Studio give a syntax error is this ASP markup?

Tags: asp.net, html, markup

Using Visual Studio 2012, the following code is syntaxically correct:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name", "Name : {0}") %>' />
```

Whereas the following is throwing `Newline in constant` error in the ASP markup (notice the `&nbsp;`) (`~`'s are exact VS red underlining):

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name", "Name&nbsp;: {0}") %>' />
                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Despite the error, the second code works "as expected", ie. a non-breakable space is added before the `:`.

Any idea why?